# What is formula to convert a "uint8 RGB pixel" to "uint8 grayscale pixel" value?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I was using the following equation to convert an RGB image to a grayscale image, however it doesn't seem to be working properly.

```
gray_pixel = (r_pixel + g_pixel + b_pixel) / 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably having issues because `r_pixel`, `b_pixel` and `g_pixel` are integers and therefore when you try to take the average of the three, you are getting an incorrect result because any addition or division of these numbers is *also* forced to be a `uint8` meaning that you can't properly add the values together if red, green, and blue are all 255.

```
uint8(255) + uint8(255) + uint8(255)
%   255
```

You will want to first convert them all to floating point numbers.

```
gray_pixel = (double(r_pixel) + double(g_pixel) + double(b_pixel)) / 3;
```

If you really need a `uint8` grayscale image, you can then cast the result as `uint8`

```
gray_pixel = uint8(gray_pixel);
```

That being said, this isn't really the best way to create a grayscale image from an RGB image. The easiest way with MATLAB is to just use the built-in function [`rgb2gray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2gray.html)

```
grayim = rgb2gray(img);
```

As far as the actual formulation that they use is [BT.601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rec._601)

```
gray_pixel = 0.2989 * r_pixel + 0.5870 * g_pixel + 0.1140 * b_pixel;
```

Comment: I needed this value for individual pixel. This seems to be working fine. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

In additional to advice above to use rgb2gray, I would like to say that problem with your formula, that is a sum not fit into  uint8, as it bounded by 255. You can first convert numbers to uint16, compute the average and then convert the result to uint8.

```
 gray_pixel = uint8([uint16(r_pixel) + uint16(g_pixel) + uint16(b_pixel)] / 3)
```